# Ternary relations, relational product and fields which are themselves relations

Tags: logic, relational-algebra, alloy

In the Alloy tutorial http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/frame-FS-3.html, we define the following in the FileSystem:

```
contents: Dir lone-> FSObject,
parent: FSObject ->lone Dir
```

In

```
// A File System
sig FileSystem {
  root: Dir,
  live: set FSObject,
  contents: Dir lone-> FSObject,
  parent: FSObject ->lone Dir
}
```

I just can't understand the following explanations:

> These are ternary relations, defined using the relational product operator ("->"). Think of them as fields which are themselves relations. The contents relation maps each file system to a binary relation from directories to file system objects. Similarly, parent relates each file system to file system objects to directories.

Can someone explain me with a different example and in other words?

Answer (score 0):

A relation contains rows that have a value for each column. It holds the rows that make some true *proposition* (statement) from some *predicate* (statement template) parameterized by its fields.
    -- the (X, Y) rows where person X loves person Y
    Loves

```
X      Y
------------
Rick   Ilsa
Victor Ilsa
Ilsa   Rick
Ilsa   Victor
Louis  Louis
```

A value is a member of a particular set. We say that the set is its type. A variable's type is the type of the values it can hold. A relation value is an element of the set that is the "product" of the types of its fields.

The value of `Loves` is a member of the set of all relations with `X` a member of `Person` and `Y`is a member of `Person`. So `Loves` and its value are of type `Person -> Person`.

All the quote is saying is that the type of a column can be a relation.

```
-- the (X, Z) rows where Z is the (A, B) rows where X will fly to A in B
Itinerary
```

*Spoiler alert!*

```
X       Z
--------------------------
Rick    A           B
        ------------------
        Paris       Spring
        Casablanca  Summer
Ilsa    A           B
        ------------------
        Paris       Spring
        Casablanca  Fall
        Lisbon      Fall
Victor  A           B
        ------------------
        Casablanca  Fall
        Lisbon      Fall
```